# Brief form of document.getElementById(), such as jQuery "dollar-sign" method: $()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid, dollar-sign

I want to use something like:

```
$('#some_id')  // or anything as brief as this
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById('some_id')
```

But **not by use of `jQuery`**!

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Please try to clarify (add some examples of what you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: Or you can suppose this problem: **How can use only that part of `jQuery` that simplifies your access to `document.getElementById()`?**

Comment: Still don't really understand what you want. Sorry.

Comment: @Dekel, I made it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just make a function with a short name that returns the result of getElementById, for example,

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

then use it as...

```
var element = $('elementId');
```

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach, as if you ever do want to use jQuery you will have horrible clashes, but you could just pick a different short name for your function.

Edit:
It's actually not necessary to declare a function here, you can simply alias `document.getElementById` to `$` because they accept the same arguments.

```
var $ = document.getElementById;
```

Comment: This is nearly 100% correct, except that this would only allow `id`'s to be used. A for effort + upvoted!

Comment: Oh... OP only wishes to have `ID`'s returned, carry on

Answer (score 4):

Although I like the accepted answer, for clarity: I'd like to add the `document.querySelectorALl` method, so you can actually recreate the `$(selector)` method

```
function $(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Bear in mind though, this returns either an element, or a NodeList containing the elements

```
$('.hello') // returns all elements with class='hello'
$('#hello') // returns the element with id='hello'
$('a') // returns all links
```

Comment: Yes. It is a better way but [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933672/brief-form-instead-document-getelementbyid-such-jquery-method-dollar-sign#answer-40935450) matches the question.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById()` is `$('#your_id')` in jQuery. If that's what you mean.

Comment: This is not an answer. OP's already written the same in their post, so obviously knows about it.